# Is there a setting for Dygraph library to break the line if the difference between points is larger than x minutes?

Tags: javascript, charts, dygraphs

Yesterday I started using the Dygraph library for some charts and the only issue I have so far is that I didn't found a way to disable the "connecting line" between points if the time difference is larger than x minutes, as you can see in the photo bellow, there is an large area in my graphs where the lines continues, even if I have no data for those hours.

[Area marked with RED should not have a stright line to connect the left side of the graph with the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3IaX.jpg)

Is there a setting / variable I can add to the js file, to break the line, if the time between points is higher than x minutes ?

Here is a part of my data :

```
"2017-09-08 22:26,4262.00\n"+
"2017-09-08 22:36,7095.00\n"+
"2017-09-08 22:46,7177.00\n"+
"2017-09-09 09:16,5833.00\n"+
"2017-09-09 09:26,3903.00\n"+
```

As you can notice I have no rows between hour 22:46 and 09:16, I want to have an empty graph between that period.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by introducing an artificial missing value:

```
"2017-09-08 22:26,4262.00\n"+
"2017-09-08 22:36,7095.00\n"+
"2017-09-08 22:46,7177.00\n"+
"2017-09-09 00:00,\n"+
"2017-09-09 09:16,5833.00\n"+
"2017-09-09 09:26,3903.00\n",
```

Here's a [full example](https://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/10446/). For a more thorough discussion, see the [missing data](http://dygraphs.com/tests/independent-series.html) page.